Can I know which version of K8s multi-version api is applied
I'm the owner of a CRD that defines an API. Given current API is foo.io/v1, I want to make a significant behavior change to the API, so I create a foo.io/v2, the element in the api is completely the same as the v1, but I'm going to make the v2 has a totally different behavior. In my controller, how I can differentiate them, know which version is applied by user, let the controller take different actions?
When I get the object in controller, it cannot tell me which version of the object is originally applied.

The script (your controller) uses the Kubernetes client library to watch for events on the custom resource with the exact version. Then It reacts to events. For example, in python
from kubernetes import client, config, watch

def main():
    config.load_incluster_config()
    api_instance = client.CustomObjectsApi()
    group = "example.com"
    version = "v1"  # Here is the VERSION
    namespace = "default"

    # Watch the events
    while True:
        stream = watch.Watch().stream(
            api_instance.list_namespaced_custom_object,
            group, version, namespace, ...
        )
        for event in stream:
            custom_resource = event['object']
            event_type = event['type']
            resource_name = custom_resource['metadata']['name']
            resource_data = custom_resource.get('spec', {})
            do_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Therefore you can have 2 deployments, each for one version. Or in the same script, watching 2 times the events, each for a different version.
